# self join crash with NULL value exception

Tags: scala, slick

i'm trying to join rows with other rows in the same table, aka a self join.

this is my model (a bit simplified, my version has 12 more cols):

```
case class Log(id: Option[Long], createdAt: Date, state: Int, duplicateOf: Option[Long] = None)

class LogsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Log](tag, "log") {
  def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def createdAt = column[Date]("created_at", O.NotNull)
  def state = column[Int]("state", O.NotNull)
  def duplicateOf = column[Option[Long]]("duplicate_of", O.Nullable)

  def * = (id, createdAt, state, duplicateOf) <> (Log.tupled, Log.unapply _)
}
```

this is my query:

```
 val q = for {
    (logs, duplicates) <- Tables.logs.filter(_.duplicateOf.isEmpty) leftJoin Tables.logs on (_.id === _.duplicateOf )
  } yield (logs, duplicates)
```

which is failing with a

```
[SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column Path s2._19]
```

Since the column is defined as Option[Long] and Nullable, i'm not really sure why it fails. Any suggestion?

Comment: I see no (good) reason for allowing null on a primary key

Comment: @thoefer how would you create a new element then (using PG auto imcrement) just using the case class of the model + insert wasnt working for me.

Comment: `val id: Column[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)` - on PG side this is a (auto-incrementing) `bigserial`. Allowing null on a primary key possibly destroys `row-identity`.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Slick have some limitations on left and right and fullOuter join for nullable row.
But you can handle nullable rows like(may be this is not a best approach)

```
def getLogs()(implicit session: Session): List[(Log, Option[Log])] = {
    (for {
      (logs, duplicates) <- Tables.logs.filter(_.duplicateOf.isEmpty) leftJoin Tables.logs   on (_.id === _.duplicateOf)
   } yield (logs, (duplicates.id, duplicates.createdAt.?, duplicates.state.?,    duplicates.duplicateOf))).list
  .map {
    case (log1, log2) =>
      (log1, if (log2._1.isDefined) None else Some(Log(log2._1, log2._2.get, log2._3.get, log2._4)))
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you want to use `filterNot` instead of `filter`.